# C++ vector elements dynamically instantiated or not

Tags: c++, vector, new-operator

I am starting to learn c++ and have a simple question.
When i have `std::vector` which schould hold some custom objects.
Is it better to create those object with the `new` operator or should i just normally instantiate the objects and pass it to the vector? I am just wondering, because in `Java` i do not need to care about this.

i.e. i am creating a bunch of objects in the main class. Then i pass these objects in a vector which is contained in another class Is it okay to instantiate the object on the stack? Or should i always do it with the `new` operator (then i have to take care that the objects get deleted somewore).  or is the simple answer: it depends on your program?

cheers

Comment: Are you planning to use c++03 or c++11?

Comment: "or is the simple answer: it depends on your program?". Yes

Comment: c++11. but could you please point out why this is important anyway :-)

Comment: For c++03, I would suggest that you read up on: copy construction and then decide yourself.
For c++11, I would suggest that you read up on: smart pointers, copy construction, and move construction and then decide yourself.

Comment: In C++11 you'd use `emplace` rather than constructing the object yourself.

Comment: 1) Unlearn Java. 2) Get a good book. 3) Learn C++ without bringing Java ways into C++. Seriously. Otherwise you will end up with something rubbish.

Comment: Your question really is "should I use a vector of objects or a vector of pointers to objects?" Whether or not you use `new` depends upon that and only that. Luckily, that is the question that has been answered below.

Answer (score 2):

Simple is better.   Just store the values directly in the vector, unless the values are (a) huge, (b) non-copyable (even then we have std::move in C++11), or (c) owned by another object (use shared_ptr or raw pointers).

Comment: "sroring the values directly in the vector" means what? instntiating them on the stack and just pass it to the vector?

Comment: Yes, keeping in mind that when you push_back(), the vector will copy your value into its own memory, which is heap allocated.  For most use cases, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are the objects polymorphic (i.e. are you making nontrival use of inheritance)? Do you plan to share object references? Are they noncopyable? If the answer to these questions are no, you're likely best off storing them by value (use emplace).

If you are storing them by reference, you should be using some variety of smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the objects. If they are just small structs holding a couple of simple values then you don't really need to use `new`. But if your objects are very large or have other classes inside of them, then I would pass pointers of them to your vector.

The thing to realize is that `std::vector` stores copies of the objects, so if they are smaller then you don't care about copying. Also if these objects have any dynamic memory usage inside them, then you should probably overload the copy-constructor, because this is what is used to make these copies.